# 2D Arrays - Error with counting neighbours algorithm (Conway's Game of Life)

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I am having problems with Conways Game of Life, specifically using a 2D integer array to count the number of true value "neighbours" from a 2D Boolean array (all arrays were scaled down to 10x10 for simplicity).

I am using the following Algorithm for counting the number of neighboring cells within a 2D Boolean Array;

```
public static int neighbourCount(boolean[][] inputArray, int x, int y)
{
    // X and Y co-ordinates for all spots around current point
    int[] xVals = {x - 1,   x - 1,  x - 1,  x,      x,      x + 1,  x + 1,  x + 1};
    int[] yVals = {y - 1,   y,      y + 1,  y - 1,  y + 1,  y - 1,  y,      y + 1};

    int nCount = 0;

    // Count neighbours algorithm
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (xVals[i] > 0 && yVals[i] > 0 && xVals[i] < 10 && yVals[i] < 10)
        {
            if (inputArray[(xVals[i])][(yVals[i])])
            {
                nCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return nCount;
}
```

I used this algorithm specifically to prevent out of bounds exceptions.

I used the following algorithm to print out the values;

```
    // Print countNeighbours Algorithm
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            countNeighbours[i][j] = neighbourCount(gameBoard, i, j);
            System.out.print(" " + countNeighbours[i][j]);
        }

    System.out.println("");
    }
```

I tested the algorithm with the following initial values ( * = true Boolean values );

```
. . . . * . . . . .
. . . * * * . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
```

The expected results should have been;

```
. . 1 3 3 3 1 . . .
. . 1 2 3 2 1 . . .
. . 1 2 3 2 1 . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
```

The results that were given were;

```
. . 1 2 3 2 1 . . .
. . 1 1 2 1 1 . . .
. . 1 2 3 2 1 . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
```

I had considered using an alternative algorithm using a slightly bigger sized array to prevent the out of bounds exceptions, however it consisted of many if statements and looked very messy.

Any helpful insight to this problem would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger? If you haven't learned how, now would be a great time. This program is somewhat simple, but as you get more and more complex it will be hopeless to debug problems by just staring at a block of code. I did look at your program but the error didn't jump out at me.

Answer (score 4):

Preumably you should be testing >= 0, not > 0, when testing indexes are in bounds?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Made your changes and worked perfectly. Thanks alot.